# Nested and mixed lookaheads and lookbehinds?

Tags: regex, nested, regex-lookarounds

For example, I define "keyword *foo* near start of string" as this regex:

```
(?<=^.{,10})foo
```

And I define "short string" as this regex (or equivalently, 30 chars or less):

```
^(?=.{,30}$)
```

Now the question is, I want to match "keyword *foo* near start of a short string" with one single regex, but am unsure how to do it. The matched text must be "foo" so surrounding text are supposed to be handled properly (with lookarounds).

This one is what I've tried and it obviously doesn't work:

```
^(?=.{0,30)$)(?<=^.{,10})foo
```

This one works but matches too much text, I only want *foo*, not *aafoo*:

```
^(?=.{0,30)$).{,10}foo
```

Expected inputs and outputs:

```
aaaaaaaaaaa => None
aafooaaaaaa => "foo" (at position 2-5)
aaaaaaaaaaafoo => None (Too far from start of string)
aafooaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa => None (String too long)
```

I'm using a 3rd-party PyPI package `regex` (not the built-in `re`) on Python 3.

Comment: expected input output?

Comment: @TheScientificMethod If only my description isn't clear enough. I'll add some.

Comment: I'd advise against merging these to regexes. They do two different things: One extracts data (the `foo`), while the other validates the input. Don't conflate the two. Do input validation first, and data extraction later.

Comment: @Aran-Fey If there were an environment where any other executable code runs slower (more complex) than regex compiling/matching/substituting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the lookbehind, when you match the start of the string with `^`, use lookahead to ensure that the end of the string is less than 30 characters away, so as not to consume any characters in the lookbehind - *then* you can consume up to 10 characters in the lookbehind to get to `foo`. You can use the pattern

```
(?<=^(?=.{0,30}$).{,10})foo
```

See:

```
pattern = r'(?<=^(?=.{0,30}$).{,10})foo'

# matches
print(regex.search(pattern, 'text foo text'))

# fails, foo is more than 10 characters away from the start of the string:
print(regex.search(pattern, 'text text text foo text'))

# fails, string is more than 30 characters long:
print(regex.search(pattern, 'text foo text long long string long long string long long string long long string'))
```

Output:

```
<regex.Match object; span=(5, 8), match='foo'>
None
None
```